# spring-boot-maven-plugin repackage vs executable configuration

Tags: spring-boot, maven, spring-boot-maven-plugin

It seems there are two ways of making the jar produced by maven executable. One way is to set a goal in executions

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Another way, which I find to do the same, is to set configuration `executable` to true

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I've failed to find explanation for what's the difference between the two. Would anyone be able to explain?

Comment: Take a deeper look into the documentation of the spring-boot-maven-plugin https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/repackage-mojo.html

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.4.RELEASE/maven-plugin/examples/repackage-classifier.html).

> If you are using `spring-boot-starter-parent`, the `repackage` goal is executed >automatically in an execution with id `repackage`.

So when you do `mvn clean package` it executes `mvn clean package spring-boot:repacakge` for you. In order to check it go to target dir and you will see two different jars one with `origin` suffix which was generated by plain maven package and another one is executable generated by `repackage`